# How do you disable autoplay in the YouTube app when you are watching a playlist?

Tags: youtube

I have set autoplay to off in settings, but when I enter a playlist video, the next video still starts when the one I am on ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't set Autoplay to OFF for playlist.
Since it is a play**list**, so the concept of Autoplay doesn't lies here as you are playing a *list* and not a *single video*.

Comment: It looks like you're right.  I had thought that you could turn off autoplay for playlists in the browser but not in the app, but I cannot do it in the browser, so I was mistaken.

Comment: Your answer is correct, and your reasoning makes sense at first glance. But remember that a playlist is often *not* intended to be played as a long chain, but rather just a grouping of videos. For example, the YouTube default Favorites "playlist", and the "playlists" that channels use to organize their content by topic, are really just groups of videos.

Comment: Google's main concept is to make you watch more whether you want it or not

Answer (score 1):

Despite being commonly used to organise channels videos in to themes, rather than as more traditional playlists, this is an oddly unavailable option.
This is a particularly odd omission as there is ordinarily an auto-play on/off toggle within the video controls and this option used to be available for playlists in the browser, but only when not using a playlist.
While a bit of a cop-out, your best bet is to use a browser such as chrome and a plugin to do this for you.

Comment: Note that Chrome on Android doesn't allow browser extension though.

Answer (score 0):

If you install NewPipe Legacy from the F-Droid store, you can share a single video from the playlist to it and play it this way. This way, it will stop playback when the video finished.

Answer (score -2):

Turnoff the loop option. Check the image[image]

Comment: That is to loop the whole playlist, i.e. if the playlist ends it will be played again from starting if loop is enabled.